# Ubuntu 20.04: Gnome file manager freezes after cifs mount on home directory

Tags: 20.04, mount, pam, openldap, sssd

as part of a project I need to mount individual cifs-directories from a Samba DC on the home directory of individual users.
The login-process authenticates against an OpenLDAP via SSSD and the mount is handled by pam_mount.

While the authentication and mount at first works fine, the file manager (GUI) freezes upon opening and stops the proccess subsequently. It then opens it later on (after 10+ Minutes) but many of the home folders (Documents, Downloads etc.) are not accessible.

If you look at it now within the terminal, the samba-share is mounted and you can access the /home-directory of the user and all files perfectly fine (also including read/write permissions and correct IDs from the LDAP).

My pam_mount.conf.xml configuration is as follows:

> volume fstype="cifs" server="*placeholder*" path="HOME/%(USER)" mountpoint="/home/%(USER)" options = "workgroup=*placeholder*" />

I also tried out several other options but none worked for me.

Is this a known problem? Does anybody have an idea how to fix this or is Ubuntu intentionally designed to not allow mounts on home-directories?

PS: I am not a native english speaker, so I apologize in advance for weird phrasing/spelling.

Comment: You do not want to mount a file system not supporting linux permissions as a home folder. Use NFS instead.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, nfs does not work with how the Samba-Share is configured.

Comment: I had similar problems. You may be affected by this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1820859). In the end, only an upgrade to 21. (4 or 10) helped me. Because this nautilus bug wont be fixed in older versions.